# Application walkthrough when opened for the first time

Tags: iphone, ios5

How do you setup in your application to show little bubbles with text and block the rest of the screen from being used and only allow a small section / button to be pressed. I am wanting to create a walkthrough to show users how to use the application and where to find things within the application when it is opened for the first time.

I would like to dim the rest of the application except for the part I want them to click on. Is there a framework already with these features?

Comment: I have got a code on GitHub that does a similar job. 
Here's the link: https://github.com/karanthakakr04/Walkthrough-Demo.git
I hope it serves your need. Also there's this reference tutorial if someone needs it: https://youtu.be/tNCsQe5vfRk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no frameworks that provide this functionality, as far as I know.

One way you could do this though is to have a set of overlay images which you overlay over the whole screen the first time the user goes to that screen. To determine if the user has already been to a screen, I suggest you look at [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). To create the overlay images, I'd make the image the full size of the screen (i.e. 460x320 if you are showing the status bar) and then have transparent sections where you want to "see through" to the element below. Add a gesture recogniser to the overlaid image view to detect a tap and then hide the image and set the flag in `NSUserDefaults` to make it not happen the next time the user goes to that screen.

Comment: I have got a code on GitHub that does a similar job. 
Here's the link: https://github.com/karanthakakr04/Walkthrough-Demo.git
I hope it serves your need. Also there's this reference tutorial if someone needs it: https://youtu.be/tNCsQe5vfRk

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get a better answer, you could look at MAAttachedWindow [on the page at this link](http://mattgemmell.com/source/). It's written for Cocoa, not Cocoa Touch, so you would have to convert it. I am considering doing this myself. You might find it to be worth the trouble, but I haven't looked at every detail, yet, so I couldn't say for sure. There are only tow files that are involved (.m and .h).